# Label reviews in file using sentiwordnet

Tags: python, python-3.x, label, sentiment-analysis

I'm very new to Sentiment analysis and need some guides. I have a text file of movie reviews and I want to label each review with pos/neg score using sentiwordnet. What steps I should follow to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out NLTK. The package has an interface for sentiwordnet that is simple to use. http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiwordnet.html

As for the actual sentiment analysis, there are a lot of guides on how to train machine learning models for this task. And sentiwordnet scores can used as features for the classifier.

If you want to use just that alone, the simplest model would be to sum the scores of all the words in the review and make a final judgement.

Check out http://sentiment.christopherpotts.net/ if you want a simple starter to sentiment analysis.

Edit - Some more guides https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/01/19/sentiment-analysis-with-python-and-scikit-learn/

http://mlwave.com/movie-review-sentiment-analysis-with-vowpal-wabbit/